# Is there a way to keep a service up at both MASTER and SLAVE with Keepalived?

Tags: keepalived

I'm using a Red Hat 6.6 and my keepalived version is v1.2.7.

I have configured two servers with keepalived and the failover is working as expected, nothing much about that. But I do have a service that I want to maintain up even if the keepalived state isn't MASTER.

Is there a way to keep a service up and being checked (like checking if it is up) at both MASTER and SLAVE with Keepalived? Or should I remove it from keepalived and just add a script to the crontab?

Thanks in advance!